# How to perform cumulative calculations in pandas that restart with each change in date?

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, cumsum

This is a simplified version of my data:

```
    Date and Time           Price   Volume
0   2015-01-01 17:00:00.211 2030.25 342
1   2015-01-01 17:00:02.456 2030.75 203
2   2015-01-02 17:00:00.054 2031.00 182
3   2015-01-02 17:00:25.882 2031.75 249
```

I would like to calculate cumulative volume per day, so that the end result would be something like:

```
data['cum_Vol'] = data['Volume'].cumsum()
```

Output:

```
    Date and Time           Price   Volume cum_Vol
0   2015-01-01 17:00:00.211 2030.25 342    342
1   2015-01-01 17:00:02.456 2030.75 203    545
2   2015-01-02 17:00:00.054 2031.00 182    182
3   2015-01-02 17:00:25.882 2031.75 249    431
```

Notice how instead of doing the regular `cumsum()`, the calculation re-starts when there's a change in Date, in the example from 2015-01-01 to 2015-01-02.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to set 'Date and Time' as the index and then use `groupby` with `TimeGrouper` to group the dates. Then you can apply `cumsum()`:

```
>>> df2 = df.set_index('Date and Time')
>>> df2['Volume'] = df2.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D'))['Volume'].cumsum()
>>> df2
                           Price  Volume
DateandTime                             
2015-01-01 17:00:00.211  2030.25     342
2015-01-01 17:00:02.456  2030.75     545
2015-01-02 17:00:00.054  2031.00     182
2015-01-02 17:00:25.882  2031.75     431
```

You can always reset the index again afterwards.

Comment: There's a problem. I only want to cumsum the column 'Volume'. I want to keep the Price column intact. Is that possible?